# Set a variable value by Resful Api response

Tags: javascript, api, rest

I've created a Restful API and when getting product details I want to set the value of a variable called category equal to the product.Category_Name.  I tried it many ways but with no success.
Thanks in advance!

```
 function fetchProductDetail() {
            fetch('https://something.com')
                .then(response => {
                    return response.json();
                })
                .then(data => {
                    console.log(data);
                    const html = data.map(product => {
                        return `
                        <div class="row">
                        <div class="column50"> 
                        <span class="discount">${product.Discount}</span>
                        <img style="width: 300px; height: auto;" src="${product.Image}"
                        alt="">
                        </div>
                        <div class="column50" style="margin: 20px;"> 
                        <span class="category" id="categoryy"> ${product.Category_Name} </span>
                        <span class="dealer"> ${product.Suppliers_Name} </span>
                        <br>  <br>
                        <div class="stars">
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star"></i>
                            <i class="fas fa-star-half-alt"></i>
                        </div>
                        <div class="price"> ${product.Final_Price} <span> ${product.Default_Price} </span> </div>
                        <span style="padding:0 .7rem; font-size: 1.7rem;"> ${product.Description} </span>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                        `;
                    })
                        .join("");
                    console.log(html);
                    document
                        .querySelector('#productDetails')
                        .insertAdjacentHTML("afterbegin", html);
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        }
        
        fetchProductDetail();
```

I tried setting an ID to the HTML return

```
<span class="category" id="categoryy"> ${product.Category_Name} </span>
```

```
var category = document.getElementById("categoryy").innerHTML;
```

or set it in

```
...
.then(data => {
console.log(data);
const html = data.map(product => {
var category = product.Category_Name
return ...
```

Response of API-Request
There are a total of 4 products at the moment, but I'm showing only one.

```
[
{
"ID": 255,
"Name": "Strawberry White",
"Description": "A perfect combination of sweet and sour! Creamy strawberry ice cream with thin streaks of strawberry sauce - dipped in white chocolate",
"Default_Price": 3.89,
"Discount": 0,
"Final_Price": 3.89,
"Expire_Date": "2023-09-12T00:00:00.000Z",
"Available_Quantity": 50,
"Category_Name": "Frozen",
"Suppliers_Name": "Bestway Wholesale Ltd.",
"Discount_Start_Date": null,
"Discount_Final_Date": null,
"Image": "https://d2rfo6yapuixuu.cloudfront.net/hbc/h2d/11189140619294/8722700054375_1612907135566_master_axfood_400"
}
]
```

Comment: Can you show me the response of the Api-Request?

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt Sorry for the late answer. I added it to the question above.

Answer (score 0):

try to assign "category" as public